# facebook like button and pagination implementation in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, facebook-like

I need advice,

I've installed facebook/google+ on my wordpress category pages.

For example: http://www.sandrophoto.com/category/famous-photographers/

First page has allot of likes, but second and third page only few. This pushed me to think, maybe I should unite those pages into one.

And instead of having separate 'like button' for urls, I would point button only to first page.
http://www.sandrophoto.com/category/famous-photographers/page/2/
http://www.sandrophoto.com/category/famous-photographers/page/3/

Does this make sense?

Any ideas how to implement this? I use this currently:

```
//get current archives url for fb like and open graph
function get_current_archive_link( $paged = true ) { 
        $link = false; 

        if ( is_front_page() ) { 
                $link = home_url( '/' ); 
        } else if ( is_home() && "page" == get_option('show_on_front') ) { 
                $link = get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ); 
        } else if ( is_tax() || is_tag() || is_category() ) { 
                $term = get_queried_object(); 
                $link = get_term_link( $term, $term->taxonomy ); 
        } else if ( is_post_type_archive() ) { 
                $link = get_post_type_archive_link( get_post_type() ); 
        } else if ( is_author() ) { 
                $link = get_author_posts_url( get_query_var('author'), get_query_var('author_name') ); 
        } else if ( is_archive() ) { 
                if ( is_date() ) { 
                        if ( is_day() ) { 
                                $link = get_day_link( get_query_var('year'), get_query_var('monthnum'), get_query_var('day') ); 
                        } else if ( is_month() ) { 
                                $link = get_month_link( get_query_var('year'), get_query_var('monthnum') ); 
                        } else if ( is_year() ) { 
                                $link = get_year_link( get_query_var('year') ); 
                        }                                                
                } 
        } 

        if ( $paged && $link && get_query_var('paged') > 1 ) { 
                global $wp_rewrite; 
                if ( !$wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() ) { 
                        $link = add_query_arg( 'paged', get_query_var('paged'), $link ); 
                } else { 
                        $link = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( $link ) . trailingslashit( $wp_rewrite->pagination_base ) . get_query_var('paged'), 'archive' ); 
                } 
        } 
        return $link; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For both platforms allow you to specify the URL you want Liked/Plused, rather than them trying to determine the URL from the page location and or other meta data.  Just specify the same URL in the plugin code to be used on both pages.

Facebook HTML5 version of the plugin would need to be updated like:
`<div class="fb-like" data-href="{your URL}"></div>`

and Plus 1 
`<g:plusone annotation="inline" href="{your URL}"></g:plusone>`

Comment: yes I know that. problem is that I use complicated system to determine the url :) combination of permalinks and custom php code.

I updated original post with the code I use.

Comment: It might be as simple as truncating the URL after the occurrence of "/page/".

Comment: funny thing! I wrote preg_replace with regex to eliminate /page/, but than I noticed: "$paged = true" setting this to false makes everything perfect! :)))

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear you got it working.  OG tags, while they look simple at first look, they sure can be difficult to work with in the real world!!